# How do I denote only some zeros as significant

Tags: notation, significant-figures

I want to write 45,000 with some numbers of significant figures.

It's really easy to write it with 2 significant figures: 45,000

5 significant figures is also easy: 45,000.

6 and up is also easy: 45,000.0

But how do I write it with 3 or 4 significant figures? I know it can be done with scientific notation, but I want to see if there's a way without it, since scientific notation can sometimes make the size of a number less visually obvious. Is this just a lexical gap with the notation, or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

use scientific notation:

2 significant digits can be represented by: $4.5 $x$(10^4)$

3 significant figures can be represented by: $4.50 $x$(10^4)$

4 significant figures can be represented by: $4.500 $x$(10^4)$

Comment: Is scientific notation the only way to note that?

Comment: That was what I was taught in school. I have never seen another way to do it. Multiple sources also do it this way:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures https://www.rpi.edu/dept/phys/Dept2/APPhys1/sigfigs/sigfig/node12.html

Answer (score 6):

I was taught that you could show that with an underline, so $45,0\underline00$ would have four significant figures.  I have never seen it since, so I wouldn't expect people to understand it.

Comment: I’ve seen that too. For example, here:  https://www.me.psu.edu/cimbala/Learning/General/Dimensions_units_significant_digits.pdf

Answer (score 3):

If the number has a unit U, you can abbreviate the unit and add decimals as appropriate:

2 significant figures: $45$ kU

3 significant figures: $45.0$ kU

4 significant figures: $45.00$ kU